# What does the phrase "pitch is in flight to line up your swing perfectly" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "pitch is in flight to line up your swing perfectly" in the following text from the description of the game "Ballistic Baseball":

Do you want to kick it out of the park? Just move your batter side to side in the batter’s box while the pitch is in flight to line up your swing perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just move your batter side to side in the batter’s box while the pitch
> is in flight to line up your swing perfectly.

This can be rearranged in any of the following ways:

1. While the pitch is in flight, just move your batter [from] side to side in the batter’s box  to line up your swing perfectly.

or

2. To line up your swing perfectly, just move your batter [from] side to side in the batter’s box  while the pitch is in flight.

or

3. To line up your swing perfectly while the pitch is in flight, just move your batter [from] side to side in the batter’s box.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your confusion comes from the fact that "pitch" can be a sports ground (eg "a football pitch" is the grass they play on), but another meaning of "pitch" is as a verb "*to throw*". In baseball, "pitch" can be used as a noun (eg is when the ball is thrown that is "a pitch").

> Just move your batter side to side in the batter’s box while the pitch is in flight to line up your swing perfectly.

- "In-flight" means that something is mid-air.
- "Swing" in baseball is the motion of swinging the bat to hit the ball.

So this means that you can move your batter *while the ball is in the air* in order to swing and hit it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're cutting the sentence in an unnatural place and being confused by the fact that you've broken it off in the middle of a phrase.

> Just move your batter side to side in the batter’s box while the pitch is in flight to line up your swing perfectly.

Removing some unnecessary clauses, we can simplify this to:

> Move your batter while the pitch is in flight to line up your swing.

"The pitch" is the action of throwing the ball to the catcher, so another way to put that would be, "While the ball is in the air, move your batter to line up your swing."